# Invalid Bundle Structure - AWS SDK

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I recently included AWS SDK on my application, as I needed to use the S3 service. Although I feel that including a whole bunch of framework, just to upload and download some pictures, is definitely an overkill I did not find any other options.

Everything was building without any problems. It was also running on local devices.

When I tried to archive, I got the following errors:

[image]

ERROR ITMS-90166: "Missing Code Signing Entitlements. No entitlements found in bundle 'com.amazonaws.sdk.ios.AWSResources ..."

and

ERROR ITMS-90171: "Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file "../Frameworks/AWSLex.framework/AWSResouces.bundle/AWSResources" is not permitted. You app can't contain standalone executable or libraries ...."

The only temporary solution I found was to delete the AWSResouces.bundle and then it archived without errors.

To add AWS SDK I use Carthage.

github "aws/aws-sdk-ios" "2.5.5"

Comment: It seems like you are including AWSLex.framework when you are only using AWSS3.framework and AWSCore.framework. You should remove the other AWS frameworks from your embedded libraries list.

Comment: @donkon I thought of that solution too, but I am using "https://github.com/lvillani/carthage-copy-frameworks" and the way amazon has done it means that on every update I need to manual remove the frameworks. As an alternative maybe I could fork AWSS3 and AWSCore and remove the unnecessary dependancies. I wonder why amazon choose that way and why include a standalone executable on AWSLex

Comment: you could add a script to delete the frameworks as part of your build script. They are aware of the issue, but dont have a solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I used, thanks to donkon was to use a script to delete all frameworks that were not needed. The script is the following:

```
find "${SRCROOT}"/Carthage/Build/iOS/AWS* -type d ! -name 'AWSS3*' ! -name 'AWSCore*' -maxdepth 0  -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Add that on Targets -> "Your Target" -> Build Phases

[image]

And I hope in the future Amazon will enable us to use Carthage and add only the framework we need.